# Execute files as a string with arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I was googling the topic for a few hours and couldn't find any proper solution for that.

My goal is to create a cleaner batch / vbs files that would include the executable file INSIDE the batch / vbs file **AS A STRING** so the script would run without any requirement for external files.

The only Window tool that was useful in that scenario is `certutil` but it does save the file and then access the saved file.

I'm looking for smoother solution so there there will be only 1 single file accessed to execute and there would be no possibility of missing files.

That is (obviously) not the correct syntax but just to get the idea what I'm after:

```
myNotepad=TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

%myNotepad% newfile.txt
```

Comment: You would need to save the string to a temporary file which is then invoked (or using `start` or `cmd /c` or `cmd /k`).

Comment: To execute a binary executable it must be in a regular file. Your script could create that file and then run it. Alternatively you can write the entire program you want to execute in batch, VBS, PowerShell or some other scripting language that you can assume will always be installed on the machine.

Comment: First, you'd have to decode `myNotepad` contents (need an external tool for that - or hmmmm maybe a routine can be developed in _batch_), which is a _base64_ string. Then, the executable is 57 bytes long, and I doubt it can do something (useful).

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging the file onto the batch file's icon when you run it and then you can refer to the file you dragged in with the "%1% enviroment variable.

Comment: this response has no relationship to the question, there is no file to drag, the OP is clear that everything is to remain inside the batch/vbs. _As a side note, there is no such thing as a **`"%1%`** environment variable._

Comment: Sorry I put an extra percent symbol after the %1 by mistake. And I get what they mean now I was a bit confused when I sent it

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample batch file for encoding files in Base 64 with Certutil utility.

---

### How to use it?

Just save this code on your notepad or on notepad++ or on any text editor as :
**Certutil_B64_Encoding_Files.bat** and drag and drop any file over it to be encoded

```
@echo off
Title Encoding files with CERTUTIL utility by Hackoo 2017
color 0A & Mode 83,3
If "%~1"=="" ( 
    color 0C & Mode 80,3
    echo(
    echo       You must drag and drop a file over this batch script to be encoded !
    Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & exit /b
)
@for /f %%i in ("certutil.exe") do if not exist "%%~$path:i" (
  echo CertUtil.exe not found.
  pause
  exit /b
)
set "TempFile=%Temp%\Temp_b64 
set "OutputFile=%~nx1_encoded%~x0"
If exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%" >nul 2>&1
echo(
echo         Please wait a while ... Encoding "%~nx1" is in progress ...
certutil.exe -f -encode "%~1" "%TempFile%" >nul 2>&1
(
    echo @echo off 
    echo CERTUTIL -f -decode "%%~f0" "%%Temp%%\%~nx1" ^>nul 2^>^&1 
    echo Start "%~n1" "%%Temp%%\%~nx1"
    echo Exit
)>> "%OutputFile%"
copy "%OutputFile%" /b + "%TempFile%" /b >nul 2>&1
If exist "%TempFile%" Del "%TempFile%" >nul 2>&1
Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak>nul & exit
```

---

### Encoded HTA Example: CommandLine.hta_encoded.bat

This is a result of an encoded output of a HTA file of mine named as ***[CommandLine.hta_encoded.bat](https://pastebin.com/raw/v2kyWycq)***
So, you should copy and paste this code as CommandLine.hta_encoded.bat and execute it by double click. And you will get something like this :

[image]

---

### Encoded VBS Example : DJBuzzRadio.vbs_encoded.bat

```
echo off
CERTUTIL -f -decode "%~f0" "%Temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs" >nul 2>&1
Start "DJBuzzRadio" "%Temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs"
Exit
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
UGxheSAiaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jaG9jcmFkaW9zLmNoL2RqYnV6enJhZGlvX3dpbmRv
d3MubXAzLmFzeCINClN1YiBQbGF5KFVSTCkNCiAgIERpbSBTb3VuZA0KICAgU2V0
IFNvdW5kID0gQ3JlYXRlT2JqZWN0KCJXTVBsYXllci5PQ1giKQ0KICAgU291bmQu
VVJMID0gVVJMDQogICBTb3VuZC5zZXR0aW5ncy52b2x1bWUgPSAxMDANCiAgIFNv
dW5kLkNvbnRyb2xzLnBsYXkNCiAgIGRvIHdoaWxlIFNvdW5kLmN1cnJlbnRtZWRp
YS5kdXJhdGlvbiA9IDANCiAgICAgICB3c2NyaXB0LnNsZWVwIDEwMA0KICAgbG9v
cA0KICAgd3NjcmlwdC5zbGVlcCAoaW50KFNvdW5kLmN1cnJlbnRtZWRpYS5kdXJh
dGlvbikrMSkqMTAwMA0KRW5kIFN1Yg0K
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```